# Third character to use when quote and single quote are in use

Tags: javascript, character, quotes

I don't know if there is a solution out there already that I havent found because I don't know what the general term for quotes/singlequotes is but is there a third sign that can be used?

Here is an example of what I mean:

I have a "copy text to clipboard" javascript that I normaly use in html like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="clipboardCopy('TextToCopy')">LinkName</a>
```

The clipboardCopy script looks like this:

```
function clipboardCopy(text) {

    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();

    document.execCommand('copy');

    document.body.removeChild(textArea);

}
```

But if I want another script to print these links into a div when pressing a button:

```
function CopyHtml() {
    document.getElementById('divname').innerHTML = "Links to print in div.";
}
```

it will not be allowed due to both quote and single quote already being used (if I change double quotes to single quotes then what do I change the single quotes to?). Is there a third character that can be used in these kinds of problems?

Comment: Can you show the context of where `CopyHtml` is used such that the quotes wouldn't be allowed? Don't think I understand the problem

Comment: I want the <a href="javascript:;" onclick="clipboardCopy('TextToCopy')">LinkName</a> to be placed in the "Links to print in div." box.

Comment: You could make things a lot easier by just creating the link elements with `document.createElement` and assigning the event handler to them instead of assigning strings to `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always escape with `\"` or `\'`.

Then you have also the new ES6 ` if you may need it

```js
console.log("he\"llo \"world");
console.log('he\'llo \'world');
console.log(`I'm a hello "world"`);
```

In your case for example you can simply do:

```
document.getElementById('divname').innerHTML = `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="clipboardCopy('TextToCopy')">LinkName</a>`;
```

Comment: Sorry, is stronger than me, just added a third example showing the usage of the ` character

Answer (score 1):

For cleaner, more maintainable code, I'd highly recommend attaching the listeners properly using `addEventListener`, rather than using inline handlers, which are as bad as `eval`. For example, you could have a helper function like

```
function copyOnClick(elm, text) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clipboardCopy(text);
  });
}
```

and then, instead of

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="clipboardCopy('TextToCopy')">LinkName</a>
```

you could select the `a` and then call

```
copyOnClick(a, 'TextToCopy');
```

You can do the same sort of thing when appending elements to `divName` in your `CopyHtml`. Explicitly create the element with `createElement`, then call `copyOnClick`:

```js
function clipboardCopy(text) {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
    console.log('copied, check clipboard');
}

function copyOnClick(elm, text) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clipboardCopy(text);
  });
}

function CopyHtml() {
  const parent = document.getElementById('divname');
  [['text1', 'copy1'], ['text2', 'copy2']].forEach(([aText, aCopyText]) => {
    const a = parent.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    a.textContent = aText;
    copyOnClick(a, aCopyText);
  });
}

CopyHtml();
```

```html
<div id="divname"></div>
```

This way, you don't have to worry about *any* nested quotes inside attribute values - you simply need to select the elements and add the listener you need.